# Chrome extension : Work with ZIP

Tags: google-chrome-extension, zip

Is there any way we can manipulate with ZIP files in Chrome Extensions like we do in Firefox ?

In Firefox there is [nsIZipReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIZipReader) and additional interfaces available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote [this library](https://github.com/gildas-lormeau/zip.js) for this purpose. It is used in 2 chrome extensions. It has been designed to manipulate large files.